# Maui syntax to use converter inside of a C# method

Tags: mvvm, checkbox, uicollectionview, maui

### What I'm trying to accomplish

In a `CollectionView`, I display a list of objects.  In each display there's a checkbox next to it.

Ideally, when the user checks or un-checks the checkbox I go into a method where I can do stuff with the object:

[image]

The above is fantasy code.

### The actual code

In reality, when the user checks/unchecks the box the code goes into a method, only I'm passing this object `CheckedChangedEventArgs` into the method.

I need to convert that object `ChcekedChangedEventArgs` into a bool.  (Note that I'm using the `MvvM` pattern, so I'm not working with code-behind.)
[image]

A kind soul gave me some code that will probably do the converting:

```
public class CheckedChangedArgsConverter : BaseConverterOneWay<CheckedChangedEventArgs, bool>
{
    public override bool DefaultConvertReturnValue { get; set; } = false;

    public override bool ConvertFrom(CheckedChangedEventArgs value, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to use the converter.  It seems like I have two options here:

1. Run the converter from the Xaml and have it run before the command `AddRemoveFromList` is called so I can pass in the converted Boolean, or
2. Run the converter code from the C# class, something like this:
   [image]

The fact is, I have no idea how to do **either**.  Can anyone help?

====================================================================

EDIT: the object `CheckedChangedEventArgs` getting passed into the C# method is ALWAYS null.

Here's my `Checkbox` code.  I'm using the `EventToCommandBehavior` because it's the only thing I can think of to call a command from inside the Checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"
          ScaleX="1.5"
          ScaleY="1.5"
          Color="#000063"
          HorizontalOptions="End">
    <CheckBox.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, 
                                                  Path=BindingContext.AddRemoveFromListCommand}"/>                                       
    </CheckBox.Behaviors>
</CheckBox>
```

I added `x:TypeArguments` to the Checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"
          ScaleX="1.5"
          ScaleY="1.5"
          Color="#000063"
          HorizontalOptions="End">
    <CheckBox.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                x:TypeArguments="CheckedChangedEventArgs"
                                        EventName="CheckedChanged"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=BindingContext.AddRemoveFromListCommand}" />
    </CheckBox.Behaviors>
</CheckBox>
```

And that did the trick.

Comment: `CheckedChangedEventArgs` has a `bool` property named `Value`.  Why don't you just use that?

Comment: "I'm using the MvvM pattern, so I'm not working with code-behind." - The code-behind is not breaking the MVVM pattern. The code-behind belongs to the UI layer and can be used within that layer just fine. Therefore, you could also have any event handlers in the code-behind. Now, with regards to the problem: As Jason already mentioned, you should be getting the required value already in the event args.

Comment: @Jason I'm assuming you mean do something like this inside the C# method: `if (args.Value) { // do the thing } else { // do the other thing}`.  The reason I'm not doing that is because it's always null.  In fact, I just realized the object getting passed in is ALWAYS null.

Comment: Please post the relevant XAML.  Generally a `Command` wouldn't receive any sort of `EventArgs` object as a parameter.  Or as @Julian suggests, just use the code behind.  MVVM is a pattern, not a hard and fast set of rules that you must obey.

Comment: I just showed my Checbox command as I'm assuming there's something wrong with that.  I was under the impression that the parameter was automatically passed because of the event, which is why I don't have a command parameter.

Comment: Note that the Command is inside of a `CollectionView`

Comment: you are missing `x:TypeArguments="CheckedChangedEventArgs"`

Comment: Oh yeah?  Put that inside of the `CheckBox.Behaviors`?  Hmmm.... I can't seem to put it anywhere.  Where should I put this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior#1-use-the-generic-implementation

Comment: Ah!  I was relying too much on intellisense.

Comment: I am not sure why your CollectionView's Model does not have a property for the checkbox's state (checked/unchecked) as a boolean that would just end the whole shenanigan right there

Comment: @FreakyAli it does.  I didn't know that it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a bool variable(e.g. `public bool VideoIsChecked`) to your Video model and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your Video Item(Suppose the Videl Model is `Video.cs`), then bind it to the property `VideoIsChecked` of this `CheckBox`. Of course, if you use nuget [MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features),you can simply this code.

Once we check or uncheck the `CheckBox`, the value of this variable will be updated. So, we can pass the whole Video Item.

You can refer to the following code. Here, I inherited the `ObservableObject` for the Video model not `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Video.cs**

```
public partial class Video:ObservableObject
{
    //I add a property to identify the name of the video
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool videoIsChecked;
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

Here, we can get the whole video item by following code:

```
public ICommand AddRemoveFromListCommand { get; set; }

AddRemoveFromListCommand = new Command<Video>(DoSomething);

private void DoSomething(Video item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // you also need to add some other logic codes here
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");

            }
        }
    }
```

You can refer to the whole code of MyViewModel:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Video> VideoList { get; set; }

    //define the AddRemoveFromListCommand for the CheckBox
    public ICommand AddRemoveFromListCommand { get; set; }


    public ObservableCollection<Video> SelectedVideos { get; set; }
    // you can  get all the selected Videos based on the value of property videoIsChecked
    public ICommand GetSelectedVideosCommand { get; set; }


    public MyViewModel() {
        VideoList = new ObservableCollection<Video>();// initialize the VideoList
        VideoList.Add(new Video { Title="video1", VideoIsChecked = true});
        VideoList.Add(new Video { Title="video2", VideoIsChecked = false});
        VideoList.Add(new Video { Title="video3", VideoIsChecked = false});

        SelectedVideos = new ObservableCollection<Video>(); // initialize the SelectedVideos

        AddRemoveFromListCommand = new Command<Video>(DoSomething);

        GetSelectedVideosCommand= new Command(GetAllSelectedVideos);

    }

    private void GetAllSelectedVideos()
    {
        foreach (Video video in VideoList)
        {
            if (video.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // add the video to the selectedlist
                SelectedVideos.Add(video);
            }
        }

    }

    private void DoSomething(Video item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // you also need to add some other logic codes here
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Title}");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

3.Usage example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiVideoListApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiVideoListApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding VideoList}" x:Name="myCollectionView">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <CheckBox Color="#0B4C90" IsChecked="{Binding VideoIsChecked}">
                            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.AddRemoveFromListCommand, Source={x:Reference myCollectionView}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                            </CheckBox.Behaviors>

                        </CheckBox>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       TextColor="#0B4C90"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Button Text="Get Result" Command="{Binding GetSelectedVideosCommand}"  />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

I also added a Button to get all the selected video list.

```
    // you can  get all the selected Videos based on the value of property videoIsChecked
    public ICommand GetSelectedVideosCommand { get; set; }

    GetSelectedVideosCommand= new Command(GetAllSelectedVideos);

   private void GetAllSelectedVideos()
    {
        foreach (Video video in VideoList)
        {
            if (video.VideoIsChecked)
            {
                // add the video to the selectedlist
                SelectedVideos.Add(video);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Bob,  I updated my answer using [MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features). You can check it.

Comment: this is a pattern that I'll definitely use in the future.  I sincerely appreciate it.  I'm a newbie to Maui (it's an excuse that I can only use for a few more weeks), and I learned using MvvM.  I also have deadlines, so I can't do what I normally do:  learn from the ground up by reading a textbook.  As a result there are large swaths of basic concepts that I haven't learned, such as code-behind -- I just learned MvvM and started pushing code.  That method works for smart people, but not for normal people such as myself, you know?